# ShutdownGracefully() never returns

Tags: java, netty

In this snippet of code, shutdownGracefully().syncUninterruptibly() never returns.
Is this the expected behaviour or have I misunderstood something ?
Tested with netty 4.0.35.Final

```
public class ShutdownGracefullyDemo {
    private ServerBootstrap bootstrap;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new ShutdownGracefullyDemo().initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() throws InterruptedException {
        NioEventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(group)
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
            .childHandler(new MyInboundHandler())
            .bind(2025)
            .sync()
            .channel()
            .closeFuture()
            .sync();
    }

    @ChannelHandler.Sharable
    private class MyInboundHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf> {
        Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");

        @Override
        protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg)
            throws Exception {
            String data = msg.toString(charset);
            System.out.println("Received: " + data);
            if ("quit\r\n".equals(data)) {
                shutdown();
            }
        }
    }

    private void shutdown() {
        if (bootstrap != null && bootstrap.group() != null) {
            bootstrap.group().shutdownGracefully().syncUninterruptibly();
            System.out.println("shutdown completed");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are creating a deadlock.

You are calling `shutdownGracefully` from a thread inside the current event loop, this will cause it to schedule a shutdown, and then wait until every thread is shutdown before continuing. Every thread won't shutdown because you are waiting until the loop has shut down, effectively creating a deadlock.

In a large application, there are multiple ways to solve this:

## Using a master thread:

this is solves by having a global application main thread, that calls the shutdown method.

## Adding a listener to the graceful shutdown:

Instead of:

> ```
> .shutdownGracefully().syncUninterruptibly();
> System.out.println("shutdown completed");
> ```

do

```
shutdownGracefully().addListener(e -> {System.out.println("shutdown completed");})
```

As that allows it to unwind the stack from the shutdown method and close that thread properly

Comment: Thanks @Ferrybig, now I got it. Regarding your last advise, shouldn't shutdownGracefully take care of closing all channels ? At least that's what I understand reading netty's documentation: [link](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html#shutting-down-your-application) "...It returns a Future that notifies you when the EventLoopGroup has been terminated completely and all Channels that belong to the group have been closed"

Comment: @staedler You are indeed correct for the last point, netty shuts down the channels by shutting down the children of the executor

Answer (score 0):

You can shutdown using code like below:

```
public void shutdown() {
    LOG.info("Gracefully shutdown http server ...");
    bossGroup.shutdownGracefully(2, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    workerGroup.shutdownGracefully(2, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

The method "syncUninterruptibly()" source code on class "io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise":

```
@Override
public Promise<V> awaitUninterruptibly() {
    if (isDone()) {
        return this;
    }

    boolean interrupted = false;
    synchronized (this) {
        while (!isDone()) {
            checkDeadLock();
            incWaiters();
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Interrupted while waiting.
                interrupted = true;
            } finally {
                decWaiters();
            }
        }
    }

    if (interrupted) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    return this;
}
```

Task blocked on wait() method, it will be never continue until notify(), so application can't shutdown completed.

Comment: Thanks Derek for your answer! In my snippet I took inspiration from Norman Maurer's book "Netty in action" where in the shutdown example the method `future.syncUninterruptibly()` is called after `shutdownGracefully()` and actually the underneth logic of calling shutdown and being notified when the operation completes make sense to me. But for some reason that baffles me this doesn't works as expected as no one is notifying the waiting thread.

Comment: Maybe server waiting for all client channel close, and the task execute on  this channel, like dead lock, so you can create a new thread to shutdown (or another better way).